# Using Spring Cloud Config without Git repo

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Is it possible to use Spring Cloud Config without using any Git repo at all? I'm trying to test it with a local directory with this in application.properties:

`spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file://${user.dir}/src/main/resources/config-repo`

But I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No .git at file://path/to/src/main/resources/config-repo

So is it not possible to use Spring Cloud if one is not using Git at all?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Spencer's advice, I added the following:

`spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=${user.dir}/src/main/resources/configs`

And I have a file "bar.properties" inside "configs" with the following contents:

```
foo: bar
```

But the response I get is not reading the file:

```
{
  "name": "bar",
  "profiles": [
    "default"
  ],
  "label": "master",
  "propertySources": []
}
```

The URL I'm using is http://localhost:8888/bar/default

Am I missing something else? Thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could try changing the search path to the following

```
classpath:/configs
```

Comment: Not necessary the directory is on the classpath

Answer (score 36):

Run with `spring.profiles.active=native`. See the [File System Backend](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html) for more details. You'll want to set `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations` to the dirs you want to look at.

Comment: For anyone using a Windows path (maybe, like me, you're going through the Spring Cloud tutorial on your workstation), I found that I needed the "spring.profiles.active=native" property and the git URI using this format: "spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri = file:///C:/Users/MyUser/Documents/config"

Comment: Scratch that, this is what I needed: 

"spring.profiles.active=native" and "spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=C:/Users/MyUser/Documents/config"

Answer (score 14):

For **Windows** I used it like this:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=C:\\\\Users\\\\my.user\\\\Desktop\\\\config\\\\
```

Comment: Really? It only worked when config is a git repo and its files are committed. Otherwise, the config server would not see the yml/properties files (using Camden.SR5).

Comment: Ya this doesn't work unless that directory is a git repo

Comment: For windows without git; this worked for me: `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:/C:/toybox-config-server-repo/` (1.5.10.RELEASE)

Answer (score 2):

try to make your path to the directory without specifying the name of the file:

file:///C:/Users/home/Desktop/yourProject/git-repo

Comment: file:/// (note 3 forward slashes as opposed to 2 which was the case with original question - did the trick for me!)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this following ways:

```
file:\\C:/WORKSPACE/GIT/repo
file:///C:/microservices/repo
file:///C:/Users/test/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.4.RELEASE/repo
file:\\C:/Users/test/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.4.RELEASE/repo
```

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below mentioned configurations

**Here is the Reference**

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_spring_cloud_config_server

**# Working - in Windows**

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:/C:/git-repo 

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/git-repo 

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=C:\\\\git-repo
```

**#Not Working - in Windows**

```
#spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:\git-repo
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for **Windows** (I created a config folder in /Desktop):

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///${user.home}/Desktop/config
```

The following didn't work so I used above:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file://${HOME}/Desktop/config
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I use this :

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///G:/software installed ssd/intelij/spring-boot-project/microservice-with-config-server/git
```

the **"git"** is the name of my folder I put my file **"limits-service.properties"**

Also check the git local branch, be the **"main"** not **"master"**,
If not, change it to the main.
After all check the properties are set are the same name, I made all this mistake, so I hope it is helpfull for the other people.thanks