# To read config. data, Is it right if springCloudConfigServer connects to a local GIT dir. instead of directly connecting to a GIT repo. via HTTPS URL?

Tags: spring, git, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

**[Spring Config Server - No such label: master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024161/spring-config-server-no-such-label-master/60255053#60255053)**

In the above-mentioned link, I have provided a solution as a response, which is my small experience(understanding & analysis) towards the question I have asked here.
(Sincere apologies, that you have to navigate to the mentioned link to understand my context.)

The `spring-cloud-config-server` mentioned above is a centralized module that provides a configuration response to the microservices.

I'm trying to learn this interesting ***microservices*** concept using spring-boot, spring-cloud, etc.

If we(`spring-cloud-config-server`) can directly point to a git repository & use its config data files directly as it is, then is there a need to create a local git directory, and perform all git operations 
to make it synchronized & then use it in your microservices application?

**My Concerns are:**
What I think is, If we can simply cut the chase & use GIT remote branch's HTTPS URL, then why complicate it unnecessarily? 
I'm wondering, is there a technical reason not to do so or any concept that I'm missing or haven't gone through in my current learning process.
Can there be any loopholes caused or any security concerns or violations of any programming principles?

So, which is a better programming practice?
Some similar questions didn't resolve the doubts in my understanding & hence I thought of posting this.
All/Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Config server uses the actual git protocol and has the ability to checkout branches all implemented using the jgit library.

Comment: @spencergibb, Sorry, I don't get the fact of how that might answer the concern? Like which is the more correct programming approach for an actual spring-cloud-config-server? Can you explain it in a different way? Thanks. :)

Comment: we use git, git checks out copies of the data and we operate on a copy. What you are describing doesn't involve git, just harvesting data from a website, that would be a new feature.