# How to configure database connection runtime in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I made a new Spring Boot project using the Spring Initializr. I'm building an On-premise backend so what I'm trying to achieve is that when the user opens the jar executable and the server starts, he should be able to configure the database connection by going to localhost:8080/ in his web browser. Basically the index.html will have a form with 4 fields for IP Address, Database Name, UserName and Password. When the form is submitted spring will try to connect to the database with the provided information.

I have all my entities, repositories and controllers but currently the only way i can connect to a database is with the application.properties file, but since the user wont have access to the source, there should be a way for him to configure his database.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the Spring cloud Config server to store database related properties which is capable of picking up configuration at run time. Although it is typically configured with a Git repository, you can store them locally as pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178448/using-spring-cloud-config-without-git-repo) thread.